# How to compile SASS .scss files in most basic method (without framework)

Tags: css, sass, devops

I installed Bootstrap CSS with SASS from the following repo:

```
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass
```

I ran the command `"bower install bootstrap-sass"` on the command line and this successfully installed the folder `bower_components` on my project folder. (Incidentally - I have nothing else present yet, I want to learn to bootstrap the CSS compiling first).

OK, here's what I want to accomplish:

- I want to be able to add `.scss` files to the folder I create called `resources/assets/sass/`
- I want to provision/manage so that `.scss` files I add to this directory are in turn compiled to `public/build/css/that_file_name.css`
- More practically, I would like to compile all of the .scss files into one large .css file.

My question(s) are:

- What does the compiling?
- How do I instruct it to compile the `.scss` files in the folder above in the `public/build/css/` folder?
- Must I configure new .scss files or can I set it so as to just add them to that sass folder?
- Bonus, how do I tell it to minify the output file, or not (so I can experiment with both ways)?

Comment: http://david-barreto.com/working-with-sass-bootstrap-and-gulp/

Comment: Excellent resource @BryanDellinger - he even has a repo with all the files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What does the compiling?

Compiling Sass files transforms stylesheets with Sass-specific syntax like [selector nesting](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-3) and [mixins](http://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-6) into normal CSS that can be parsed by browsers.

> How do I instruct it to compile the .scss files in the folder above in the `public/build/css/` folder?

Since you're already using Bower which is a Node.js package, I assume that you have no problem using the Node.js package [`node-sass`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-sass) instead of the original Ruby version.

First, install the package using `npm i -D node-sass`. Then, create a new script inside your project's `package.json`:

```
"compile-sass": "node-sass resources/assets/sass/main.scss public/build/css/main.css"
```

`main.scss` is now your entry point where you import Bootstrap and your other stylesheets.

```
// I don't know whether this path is correct
// Just find out the location of "_bootstrap.scss" and then create the relative path
@import "../../../bower_components/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/_bootstrap.scss";

/* Your custom SCSS */
```

Finally, to actually run the compilation, execute `npm run compile-sass` in your terminal.

> Must I configure new .scss files or can I set it so as to just add them to that sass folder?

Since you never tell `node-sass` to "compile everything inside this folder" and instead use an entry point file (`main.js`), when you want to include a new file you simply add an [`@import` directive](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#import) with a relative path to it.

> Bonus, how do I tell it to minify the output file, or not (so I can experiment with both ways)?

To minify the resulting `main.css` file, I recommend [`csso`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csso). You can install [its CLI package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csso-cli) using `npm i -D csso-cli` and then add another script to your `package.json`:

```
"minify-css": "csso public/build/css/main.css public/build/css/main.min.css"
```

You can then run that script using `npm run minify-css`. The minified file will be outputted as `main.min.css`.

Answer (score 5):

For all the question asked, the answer can be found above. But if you are just looking to compile .scss file to .css using command line, use below,

```
sass source/stylesheets/index.scss build/stylesheets/index.css
```

Make sure you have "node JS/npm" and Sass compiler installed.

If not, use this to install Node.js and npm - https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm

And use this to install Sass - https://sass-lang.com/install

Enjoy ;)